# Curiosidad sobre virtualizacion

Tags: virtualización

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una consulta:
Estoy tratando de configurar una maquina virtual, pero dice que mi pc no es compatible, pero en la bios la opcion de virtualizacion esta activada, por lo que pienso que si es compatible, ya que de lo contrario no me deberia de salir la opcion en la bios,
Que solucion me proponen o que opinan al respecto.
Esperando su pronta respuesta, Gracias
Ese mensaje es el que me da
Active la virtualizacion en la BIOS pero el problema sigue
Entre al admin de tareas-rendimiento y me sale que la virtualizacion no es compatible

Comment: Hector muestra exactamente que notificación te muestra el virtualizador.

Comment: Arriba esta la foto Mario

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que tu microprocesador soporta VT-x?

Comment: Gracias, ya solucione el problema, ejecute una iso de 32 bits y listo